# PayPal subscriptions with extra options

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

So I'm developing a website with subscription plans using PayPal as payment gateway.
I've this scenario when a user can select extra options with each plan, and
from what I gathered reading the developing docs there's no way to add extra charges while creating or subscribing a user to a plan. Please note that these charges for extras will be monthly/Yearly as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please don't use paypal subscriptions. Go with something like Stripe if you can.

Comment: I do like Stripe API, and prefer to use it as well, but unfortunately the client wants to include PayPal payment method.

Comment: good luck my friend.

Comment: Thank you @Divern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to charge a particular combination of things, create a plan for it. Store this plan in your database for later re-use if the same combination is selected.